# how to fill gaps in horizontally installed barn wood

Tags: siding

I have a barn with horizontal siding. I'm trying to figure out a way to fill the gaps and still have a nice "old barn" appearance.

Comment: How about a picture of the gaps in the nice old barn.

Comment: You might try the ship lap method.

Comment: How about "Board and Batten" technique?

Comment: This is really a design question, which is off-topic here. In addition to the other suggestions, a flat black liner behind might leave a nice rustic look by simulating actual gaps into a dark barn.